# How to load EF connection string from App.config after made it?

Tags: c#, connection-string, app-config, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

I have problem and can't find solution. 
On start I have that `App.config` file:

```
...
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="IdealsadEntities" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
...
```

In my application (**WinForm**) I read params for connection to database from **xml** file and then override App.config and got compiled file `AppName.exe.config`.

Problem is with creating **instance** of my **entities**. I used this code after creating file:

```
IdealsadEntities _db = new IdealsadEntities();
```

But in first run application `_db.Database.Connection` is **null**. In second run it reading from `AppName.exe.config` file and works fine.

### Questions:

- So my question is why first runing read empty string even if I
  rewrite this file?
- Is DbContext execute earlier?
- How to fix it, to get new connection string from rewrited file?

Answer (score 2):

Your app.config is only read upon application startup. Changes you write to it during the runtime of your application will not be noticed until you restart the program.

You can however construct your entities using a connectionstring, like this:

```
IdealsadEntities _db = new IdealsadEntities("metadata=res://...");
```

Where you replace the appropriate info in the connectionstring by the data you read from the other file.

Comment: Co calling save on this file doesn't change file params?

Comment: @WooCaSh I don't understand your question. What are file params? Do you understand my answer? As far as I get, you're trying to update the connectionstring in your app.config while your program is running. This will not work, because an app.config is only read one time, and that is before any code is run.

Comment: So config on first start is reading only and application got empty string right? In this time application also changing this file and save it, but in memory is still file before save? And in second runing it read from correct file? I good undestand it now?

Comment: So are You have any idea how to fix it? Reloading application after save file is a good idea?

Comment: I can't do that, because constructor look:
`public partial class IdealsadEntities : DbContext
    {
        public IdealsadEntities()
            : base("name=IdealsadEntities")
        {
        }` I made mistake in my question with this line.

Comment: @WooCaSh have you tried it? [Manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467(v=vs.103).aspx): `public DbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)`: _"Constructs a new context instance using the given string as the name or connection string for the database to which a connection will be made. For more information on how this is used to create a connection, see the remarks section for DbContext."_

Comment: I've tried some combination but don't know how to pass this new dbcontext to entities. Sorry for this but I'm beginner in C#